# Include row contents as labels in R plot

Tags: r, plot, label

Is there a way to include the contents of a column of a dataframe as labels showing on the plot ? Something like this image here that I pulled from the web. If I have the numbers next to the points in a column, how can I make them show up in the plot ?
[image]

Comment: Take a look at `?text`

Comment: Yep, `text()` and `row.names()`, check out http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an answer. Use `text()` as mentioned by jbaums. This example follows directly from http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html

```
attach(mtcars)
plot(wt, mpg, main="Milage vs. Car Weight", 
    xlab="Weight", ylab="Mileage", pch=18, col="blue")
text(wt, mpg, row.names(mtcars), cex=0.6, pos=4, col="red")
```